Reorder array in ascending order, ignoring negatives
Say in c++ I have an array of integers
x = {8,4,1,5,7,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};

I want to reorder it to be
x = {1,4,5,7,8,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};

so that the positive values are sorted and the -1s stay at the end.
Is there an easy way to go about this?

Are the -1's always at then end of the data?  If so sort can just sort the range that doesn't have the -1's in it.

@NathanOliver yes they are always at the end, but where the end of positives happens and the -1 starts is unknown

Only sort the range [begin, first_negative).

@NathanOliver Scrap that I've just realised I can work out the number of positives easily. So would it be as simple as std::sort(x, a) where a is the index of the last positive (or first negative)?
Thanks

@crankymidlifecrisis No problem. If the situation ever changes and the -1's become scattered in the array then 463035818_is_not_an_ai's first example will handle the sort.


Is there an easy way to go about this?

You can use a combination of std::partition to first partition the elements so that -1 is at the right side of the partition, and then std::sort to sort the numbers on the left side of the partition:
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> x = {8,4,1,5,7,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
    auto iter = std::partition(x.begin(), x.end(), [](int n) { return n != -1; });
    std::sort(x.begin(),iter);
    for (const auto& e : x) 
        std::cout << e  << " ";
}

Output:
1 4 5 7 8 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1

Note that this code works regardless of where the -1's are located.  Initially they do not have to be at the end of the vector:
See the sample demo for std::vector<int> x = {8,4,1,-1,5,7,-1,43,-1,-1,17,-1,-1}; as the test data:

this is a very nice answer to the general problem.  +1

You may consider a more generic return n >= 0; (the title of this question mentions negatives) and, maybe, std::stable_partition too.

@Bob__: std::stable_partition seems "wrong", as std::sort is used afterward.

@Jarod42 I guess it depends on how we interpret the "ignoring negatives" part of the title.

If the -1s are always at the end you can search for the first element not equal to -1 from the back and sort only the first part of the vector. If the -1s can be anywhere, you can use a custom comparator that considers a -1 not smaller than any other number, so the -1s will be placed at the back.
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector x = {8,4,1,5,7,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
    std::sort(x.begin(),x.end(),[](auto a,auto b){        
        return std::make_pair(a == -1,a) < std::make_pair(b == -1,b);
    });
    for (const auto& e : x) std::cout << e  << "\n";

    std::vector y = {8,4,1,5,7,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
    auto it = std::find_if(y.rbegin(),y.rend(),[](auto x){return x != -1;}).base();
    std::sort(y.begin(),it);
    for (const auto& e : y) std::cout << e  << "\n";
}

I searched the vector from the back to find the first element not equal to -1, because I assumed that there are more elements not equal to -1. If the -1 elements are the majority you can search from the front. Even better would be to use std::binary_search.
The custom comparator makes use of the std::pair::operator< which considers the first element first and that false compares smaller to true.
Live Demo

PS: In case you are using -1 for elements that are "empty" you should consider to use a std::vector rather than a fixed size array. If you are bound to a fixed size array, I would encapsulate the array and a size in a custom struct that exposes proper begin() and end() pointers into the array. If you do that sorting would be as simple as std::sort(x.begin(),x.end()).

You could have solved it with a one-liner (using std::begin, std::end and std::find) :)

@Fareanor yes I realized it :) Now the one line is already in the other answer and it doesnt hurt to show more than one way.

I upvoted anyway since you show more than the other answer ^^

@Fareanor I like the other answer more :P

Is there any reason you added if (a == b) return false; ? AFAIK it's already included in return a < b;

@Fareanor i first had a wrong second condition which returned true and thought I need to catch -1 < -1 before that. After correcting it the first is super fluous

This is nice since you give both a general solution and one tailored to the OP.

@Fareanor uff eventually I remembered how to write the comparator properly.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Oh nice catch ! I wouldn't have think of it  XD

With C++20 Ranges you can
std::vector v{8,4,1,5,7,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
std::ranges::sort(v | std::views::take_while([](int i) { return i > 0; }));

Demo

std::sort takes a pair of iterators to a range, so you can use it to sort only the range of positive values.
For example:
int x[] = {8,4,1,5,7,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};

std::sort(std::begin(x), std::find(std::begin(x), std::end(x), -1));

Live demo

This looks like what I'm after, thank you! Will check it works later and tick you if so :)

Searching from the back of the container might be more advantageous if there is more data then sentinels on average.

@NathanOliver You're right, but it can be less efficient if there is less data then -1 values XP

If all the -1 values are at the end, you can binary-search for the first one

@NathanOliver: and std::partition_point to lower complexity from linear to logarithmic ;-)
